# flowjs upload method is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flow-js

I'm new with flow.js, and i'm using the ng-flow implementation.
I want to do something but i don't know if it is possible or not, and if it is so, how to do this.
I have write a factory that catch all the events, and i need that when it catch the FilesSubmitted event, this factory have to upload automatically the file.
Following the flowJs documentation [here](https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js) i have found some methods and attributes for the 'file' element, but when i look in the console.log(file) for the upload() method, i didn't find it, like it doesn't exist. I supposed that maybe the resume() function call the method inside itself, but neither that thing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the official documentation:

```
<div flow-init="{target: '/upload'}" flow-files-submitted="$flow.upload()"></div>
```

As long as `flow-files-submitted="$flow.upload()"` is set with `flow-init`, the file will auto-upload once it is selected from the picker. If you remove this, you will have to create another button (similar to Pause/Resume/Cancel) and assign it to `upload()` to initiate the upload manually.

Something like this:

```
<button ng-click="$flow.upload()">Upload</button>
<button ng-click="$flow.pause()">Pause</button>
<button ng-click="$flow.resume()">Resume</button>
<button ng-click="$flow.cancel()">Cancel</button>
```